Get URL Image From Firebase Storage
i have already stored the image in the firebase storage with the path is "Avatar/Assists/0654234.jpg". and i use this code from chat gpt. But the problem i have is it's said "firebase.storage is not a function". IS there another way that i can get URL image from storage?
 const express = require('express')
     const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
     const admin = require('firebase-admin')
     const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json")
     const functions = require('firebase-functions')
        const path = require('path')
        const firebase = require('firebase/app');
     require('firebase/storage');

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDioYAzvJooHpspr8Z58bImI0s2jaIRU90",
  authDomain: "testlogin-c11b6.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "testlogin-c11b6",
  storageBucket: "testlogin-c11b6.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "598921663451",
  appId: "1:598921663451:web:8bc05bbb07d312f1650dfe",
  measurementId: "G-4N0GNYZQ8J"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL : "https://testlogin-c11b6-defaultrtdb.firebaseio.com/"
})


const app = express()
const db = admin.database();
const PORT = 80

let paths = "Avatar/Assist/0654234.jpg"
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(paths);
storageRef.getDownloadURL()
  .then((url) => {
console.log( url);

  })
  .catch((error) => {
   console.error(error);
 });


firebase.storage() is the syntax for the client-side Firebase SDKs to access files in Cloud Storage. Since you're using server-side code, this won't work there.
Instead follow the documentation on getting started with the server-side SDKs for Cloud Storage, which also includes a code sample of getting a download URL.
